# Visual Studio .NETCoreapp v3.1 & iTextSharp

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation, itext

atm im trying to create a C# Console Application with .NET Core 3.1 installed. Im working with some pdf files and im supposed to use iTextSharp. iTextSharp is only **fully** compatible with the v3.1. The Problem is somehow even that my project is with .NET Core 3.1 its installing iTextSharp with the .NETFramework Versions 4.6.1 and higher. Most of the functions are working but sadly not all and thats causing the problems for my code.

[image]

I really dont know what im doing wrong and i tried multiple ways to get it to work... like reinstalling VS (2019 latest version), repairing it, install different packages etc etc.

Thanks for any help i can get.

Comment: Try to [clean the nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`. Or close VS, delete the nuget.config under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`, then restart VS to test your project again.

Comment: Sadly it didnt help the problem is still there... did all the steps multiple times and i also tried to reinstall VS +  making a new project...

Comment: More..... close VS, delete the nuget.config file under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` and then restart VS to re-generate the new `nuget.config` file to test again.

Comment: Still no difference... :( im now trying to get the newest Version of iTextSharp, itext7 dependencie to work but its extremly different to iTextSharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is nuget package [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) itself. And it might be designed by its author.

And from the design of this nuget package, it works for `net framework` project rather than `net core`. Not sure it was designed on purpose or forgotten by the author.

**Actually**, `<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>` works well but you still want to use `Net Core` with `iTextSharp` nuget package, you could try this:

Right-click on your project-->**Properties**-->**Build**--> modify the **Suppress Warnings** with the full name `NU1701`.

[image]

The issue is a restore warning rather than an error and it will solve the restore problem. It will not affect the use of the nuget package and cannot cause any other problems.

Comment: Oh okay i thought iTextSharp is only for .NetCore v3.1 but that somehow the installation is not working so its restoring it with other .Net-stuff so that its working.
Thanks for your help.